# Finding a necessarily and sufficient condition for a uniform continuity of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Consider the function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=\max\{0,1-|x|\}$, and let $(s_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. I am asked to show to find a necessarily and sufficient condition for the series $h(x)=\sum_n s_nf(x-2n)$ is uniformly continuous.

It is obvious that $h(x)$ is well defined for all $x$, because $f(x-2n)$ is nonzero for at most one $n$. Also, it is easy to find sufficient conditions, for example, by letting $s_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$. However, how should I find a necessarily and sufficient condition?

Comment: Downvote for the question as well as my answer with no explanation! I don't see anything wrong with the question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think somebody hates me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer. Look at $h(2m)$ and $h(2m+a_m)$ with $a_m \to 0$  to see that $s_m a_m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$ for every sequence $a_m \to 0$. This implies that $s_m $ is bounded. Conversely if $s_m \to 0$ show that $|h(x)| \leq |s_m|$ on $2m-1\leq |x| \leq 2m+1$. This proves that $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} h(x)=0$. Any continuous function on $\mathbb R$ with this property is uniformly continuous. I cannot find a  necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: We have $h(2m)=s_m$ and $h(2m+\frac{1}{m})=s_m(1-\frac{1}{m})$, so $|h(2m)-h(2m+\frac{1}{m})|=|s_m|/m $, so we know that $|s_m|/m\to 0$ as $m\to \infty$, but how can we get $s_m\to 0$?

Comment: @probably123 There was  a typo in the first part. I meant to type $2m+\frac 1 2 $ and not $2m+\frac 1 m $.

Comment: But then I think I can't use uniform continuity because $|2m+\frac{1}{2}-2m|=\frac{1}{2}$.